# prestashop's "page not found" page on each front page. even the homepage itself

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I tried to run the exact same version of prestashop that I've got on my macbook pro (original), to the mac pro (new copy).

working with version 1.7.3.1

the new copy is causing a problem that each front page I try to view (for example `about-us`)  or even the homepage itself is causing the `page-not-found` error.

It's not my apache's web server error message. it's Prestashop own message that says that I tired to access a page that is not found.

I installed php using homebrew using both php 7.1 and 7.2. both produce same results

my httpd is with `mod_rewrite` enabled and there are not errors in the apache error log.

I just copied the directory to the mac pro, exported and imported the mysql database and it should be enough.

I don't want to reinstall anything. I want to better understand prestashop and this is a good way. I want to understand what went wrong and I can't access any front page. the admin pages work find.

so can anyone please provide any information that may help me investigate this issue further ?

thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I enabled mod_rewrite in httpd, but I didn't :)